# onComplete and aggregate with completionTimeout

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to run an `onCompletion()` block on my route, which contains an aggregate definition with `completionTimeout`. It seems like `onCompletion` is called before the route is actually completed, since I get log entries from `OnCompletion` before `AggregateTimeoutChecker` log entries.

How can I make `onComplete` wait for aggregation timeout?

Of course I can add a delay greater than completionTimeout to onCompletion, but that will slow down my tests a lot.

My route looks like this:

```
from(fileEndpoint)
    .bean(externalLogger, "start")
    .onCompletion()
         .bean(externalLogger, "end") // <-- Gets called too early
    .end()
    .split().tokenize("\n")
    .bean(MyBean.class)
    .aggregate(header("CamelFileName"), ...)
         .completionSize(size)
         .completionTimeout(500)
    .bean(AggregatesProcessor.class); // <-- some changes here don't arrive
                                      //     at onCompletion
```

Answer (score 1):

`onCompletion()` is triggered for each incoming exchange when it has completed the route. When using an aggregator, all exchanges not completing the aggregation finish the route at the aggregator, thus your `externalLogger` gets called for each file being aggregated.

If you want logging after the aggregation you could just call the logger after `aggregate()`.

If you need to distinguish between timeout and completion of your aggregation it could be helpful to provide a custom `AggregationStrategy` and to also implement the interfaces `CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy` and `TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy`.